# MySQL returned an empty result set (sean lahman database)

Tags: mysql, subquery, is-empty

I am working on Sean Lahman database and using mysql(phpmyadmin). I coded the query below but i got " MySQL returned an empty result set". I want to know the cost per win minimum in 2002. I don't know where is my mistake. Please help. 
Just so you know i am a newbie in sql and my mother tongue is not english. :-)

```
SELECT teams.name,
(ROUND(SUM(salaries.salary), 0))/teams.W AS costperwin
FROM salaries
JOIN teams ON salaries.teamID=teams.teamID
WHERE salaries.yearID='2002'
  AND teams.yearID='2002'
GROUP BY salaries.teamID
HAVING costperwin =
  (SELECT MIN(bb)
   FROM
     (SELECT (ROUND(SUM(salaries.salary), 0))/teams.W AS bb
      FROM salaries
      JOIN teams ON salaries.teamID=teams.teamID
      WHERE salaries.yearID='2002'
        AND teams.yearID='2002'
      GROUP BY salaries.teamID) AS ALIAS)
```